# npm install Cloning into bare repository, fatal: unable to access

Tags: git, npm, npm-install, package.json, git-subrepo

I have got problem on my droplet server. My **package.json** was having package from git repository like this:

```
"bootstrap": "git+http://git.pff.com.pl:8081/angular2-shared/Bootstrap4Eniro.git",
```

when I've changed this to:

```
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.2",
```

After npm instal,  **npm** is still trying to clone  *http://git.pff.com.pl:8081/angular2-shared/Bootstrap4Eniro.git* which does not exist anymore in **packagee.json**... and I am getting **NPM ERR**

```
Command failed: git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror http://git.pff.com.pl:8081/angular2-shared/Bootstrap4Eniro.git
Cloning into bare repository '/root/.npm/_git-remotes/git-http-git-pff-com-pl-8081-angular2-shared-Bootstrap4Eniro-git-b2c872db'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://git.pff.com.pl:8081/angular2-shared/Bootstrap4Eniro.git/': Could not resolve host: git.pff.com.pl
```

Why is that happend ?
I have cleaned npm cache, removed .git, .npm but still I am getting 
this annoying error. 
Is this because I am using **droplet** ?

I am using :

- npm 3.9.6 (on 2.xx same problem)
- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
- git 1.9.1

**UPDATE & SOLUTION**

My smart friend find out that one of our npm public package in  node_modules still has

```
git+http://git.pff.com.pl:8081/angular2-shared/Bootstrap4Eniro.git"
```

in package.json "dependencies". After putting everything in "devDependencies" it works...

Comment: okej, for sure problem is not with droplet....